# How can I speed up this Python function?

Tags: python, performance, loops, vectorization

Is there any way to vectorize this expression?

```
import numpy as np
def phase(f, dt=1):
    c = [f[0]] + [fi*dt for fi in f[1:]]
    
    s=0
    x = []
    for ci in c:
        s = (s+ci)%(2*np.pi)
        x.append(s)
    return x
```

`f` is an array of arbitrary length, `dt` is a constant.
The code does:

1. multiply the whole vector `f` but the first instance by `dt`.
2. return the partial sum i.e. `output[i] = sum(c[0:i])` modulo `2pi`.

Any idea on how to speed it up?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you already tried `numba`?

Comment: You can get small performance gain by using list comprehension instead of `for` cycle: `x=[(s + ci) % (2 * np.pi) for ci in c]`.  Also are you ok with the fact that `s` is different for all iterations?

Comment: Personally, I'd write this for loop using `for idx, ci in enumerate(c)` this way you can skip defining `s` separately and potentially save some nerve cells in debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Numpy's [`cumsum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) function to do this in a vectorized way. This should be quite a bit faster:

```
import numpy as np

def phase(f, dt=1):
    pi_2 = 2 * np.pi
    c = np.concatenate((f[:1], f[1:] * dt))
    
    return np.cumsum(c) % pi_2
```

Timings:

```
n = np.arange(5000)

%timeit original_phase(n, 3)
# 3.2 ms ± 120 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit phase(n, 3)
# 272 µs ± 12.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

np.testing.assert_allclose(original_phase(n, 3), phase(n, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one for loop is needed.

```
import numpy as np


def phase(f, dt=1):
    s = 0
    x = []
    if f:
        s = (s + f[0]) % (2 * np.pi)
        x.append(s)
    
        for fi in f[1:]:
            s = (s + fi * dt) % (2 * np.pi)
            x.append(s)
    return x
```